# pts & pcr values limit in mpegts?

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg, pts, iptv

As I know PCR stored in 42bits and PTS stored in 33bits in mpegts container

So,

```
 Max value for PCR is 2^42 = 4398046511104

 Max value for PTS is 2^33 = 8589934592

 PCR (sec) = 4398046511104 / 27 000 000 Hz = 162890,6 seconds (45 hours)

 PTS (sec) = 8589934592 / 90 000 Hz = 95443,7 seconds (26,5 hours)
```

So, 
what I must to do, if PTS or PCR reach one of this max values ?

This can be happening in iptv for continuous stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let it overflow and continue to write the low 33 bits. The demuxer will know how to handle it.

Answer (score 3):

> Max value for PCR is 2^42 = 4398046511104

This is not true.  Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36810049/6244249