# Maximum value of PCR

Tags: mpeg

What is the maximum value of Program Clock Reference(PCR) in MPEG?

I understand that it is derived from a 27MHz clock, periodically loaded into a  42bit register.

`PCR(i)=PCR_Base(i) * 300 + PCR_Ext(i)`

where PCR_Base is loaded into a 33 bits register
PCR_Ext is loaded into a 9-bit register.

So, the maximum value of PCR w.r.t 27MHz clock is:

PCR =  (2^33 - 1)*300 + (2^9 - 1) = 2,576,980,374,811.

=> (2,576,980,374,811/27,000,000) = 95443.7s = 1590.7 min = 26.5 hours

The register overflow happens after 26.5 hours of continuous streaming. Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 5):

PCR_ext(i) value should be 0 .. 299.

So the maximum PCR = (2^33-1)*300+299 = 2,576,980,377,599