# PCR value rewind before wraparound occurs

Tags: mpeg2-ts

I have a program that's analyzing the PCR value of several ts streams coming from satellite source. It all looks fine for days but sometimes after let say 17 days the program notice a PCR rewind (not a wraparound) for a certain ts stream.

The program has a build in future to detect a normal PCR value wraparound with values mentioned in the following post: [Maximum value of PCR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34646208/maximum-value-of-pcr/36810049)

A wrap around occurs each +-26h30m. Than the value resets itself to 0. I see in my analyzing program that the PCR value suddenly jumps from 26:15:34 to a 24:25:58 value. For the first value the PCR wraparound should have taken place 15 minutes later but instead it got a new PCR value and the PCR wraparound took place +- 2h5m later. I can confirm that the new PCR value (re winded value) is now the active/correct PCR value of that certain ts stream.

Does anyone recognize or can explain this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The stream might have switched to a different encoder. If this is an expected discontinuity it should be signaled using the `discontinuity_indicator` in the adaptation field.

Comment: I added the indicator you mentioned to the analyzing output of the program and had another hit on a pcr abrupt change. previous_pcr=26:09:02.433, pcr=1:28:54.443,discontinuity_indicator=0. Maybe to signaling of this indicator is not done correctly by the distributor?

Comment: @Gregory If the PCR gap is more than 100 ms and there's no discontinuity indicator then it's a PCR error.